# Having Issue on JS Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a custom pattern like this

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9@$().'"%#!&{}=+-_\n ]){3,300}$/
```

to validate user inputs in message box. As you can see I would like to allow some characters entry like `@$().'"%#!&{}=+-_\n` which are fine, but not characters like `^<>~` .

But adding the space to expression at `]`  is also validating those characters!

As you know, I have to validate the space in a message box. So can you please let me know how to fix this?

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding your problem if you are wanting to include a space character in your list of allowed characters have you tried the \s escape sequence?

Comment: Hi Zac No what I want to do is not validating characters like `<>` on above experssion

Comment: You can use `[^<>]` for this, the regex tries to match a character which is not < or >

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the space character. The problem lies with the "-" (hyphen) you have added between "+" and "_". Hyphens are supposed to denote a range hence they should be escaped when not being used in that context.

The correct regex for you would be:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9@$().'"%#!&{}=+\-_\n ]){3,300}$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Custom pattern like `/^([a-zA-Z0-9@$().'"%#!&{}=+\-_\n ]){3,300}$/`